# Architecting a simple, federated login and user profile with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I've written a single-page web application where visitors create content represented as JSON documents and stored in localStorage. I'd now like to give these visitors the ability to log in with an external identity provider (Google, Twitter, Facebook, etc) so they can upload and share their content within my application.

What's the best way to architect this project on AWS? I'm *brand new* to cloud services.

I gather I'll want an S3 bucket to store the JSON documents, and maybe a DynamoDB to store additional user profile information (like a nickname or email address), but the authentication/authorization/profile aspects (Cognito, IAM, OpenID, OAuth, and perhaps Lambda scripts to tie everything together) escape me completely. (Frankly, despite three days of reading, I'm not even sure I understand the differences/purpose of each.)

Any advice pointing me in the right direction would be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito Identity gives your users AWS Credentials with permissions, that you define, to AWS resources. In your application, your users can login using Facebook, Google, Twitter, any OIDC provider, or your own developer authentication and acquire AWS Credentials.

It looks like you want to use your own developer provider. Your implementation of this depends on your use case. However, you can use your developer provider with Cognito using the Developer Authenticated Identities feature:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html

Each user will get a Cognito Identity ID.

If your JSON objects are only meant to be used by the owner of them, you can use Cognito Sync, so that your user can retrieve these objects regardless of what device he is on when he logs into the application.

If your JSON objects need to be shared among users, you will need to develop another solution, possibly using S3, as you mentioned.

For help creating permissions, refer to here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html

Comment: Thanks, Mark. This is helpful. I'm still a little unclear on a couple details, so let me know if I'm off track: Specifically, I don't want to authenticate users myself, but rather I'd like them to log in with an external provider and then once authenticated let them store additional profile information (such as a nickname) with my application.

The JSON objects should be sharable publicly (to anyone, not just other authenticated users), but I'd like to grant users the authorization to replace or modify their own documents (but not those of other users). Can Cognito/S3 do this?

Comment: Ah, you can work with external providers as I mentioned, and store info that you decide. If you want your JSON to be read-able to *everyone who uses your app* but only write-able by the creator, this can be done through your policies. If you want to only share with a subset of users, you will need some backend between your JSON in S3 and the customer to determine if the user has access to the specified S3 Object. A good solution for this is API Gateway.

Comment: correction: you will *probably* need a backend in between the client and S3  for the last scenario describe in my previous comment. Again, it depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. Indeed, all of the content these users create should be publicly accessible, so it sounds like I don't need a backend. So, let's see if I have this right: I'll want to use Cognito for the federated login, which can be used to create an IAM user (is that right?), whose policies can be used to grant write privileges to its own S3 folder for the JSON document storage, while other profile details can be stored directly with Cognito Sync. Do I understand that right?

Comment: It won't create an IAM user. Your users will be part of Cognito Identity. And the permissions they have will be based on *roles* you define. Currently there are 2 roles: unauthenticated or autheneticated.

Comment: Excellent; thanks for your help! I appreciate it. :)